# How do we compensate for the 'elvis operator' inside of an expression?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-forms

Binding to my data from Firebase requires using the `elvis operator` otherwise everything returns `undefined`.  I just got into doing reactive forms and have implemented a component I created using my actual data from fireBase and now I'm getting an `undefined` error from the `FormGroup` which looks like this

```
createForm() {
    this.quesForm = this.fbuild.group({
        question: this.featureQuestion.question,
        id      : this.featureQuestion.id,
        name    : this.featureQuestion.name,
        answers : this.fbuild.array([])
    });
    this.setAnswers(this.featureQuestion.answers);
}
```

if I add in the `elvis operator` making it like this

```
createForm() {
    this.quesForm = this.fbuild.group({
        question: this.featureQuestion?.question,
        id      : this.featureQuestion?.id,
        name    : this.featureQuestion?.name,
        answers : this.fbuild.array([])
    });
    this.setAnswers(this.featureQuestion?.answers);
}
```

I get more errors telling me it expects an expression and or `;` and `,` every other line.  So adding the `?` here clearly doesn't work the same as it does inside the template.  How do I work around this?

Comment: The elvis operator currently is only supported in view bindings (special support from Angular). There are plans to implement it in TypeScript but that's not done yet.

Comment: You can use `question: this.featureQuestion && this.featureQuestion.question` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct usage of the ternary operator in JavaScript (and by extension TypeScript):

```
conditionToEvaluate ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse
```

For your case, you would have to do:

```
this.quesForm = this.fbuild.group({
    question: this.featureQuestion ? this.featureQuestion.question : '',
    id      : this.featureQuestion ? this.featureQuestion.id : '',
    name    : this.featureQuestion ? this.featureQuestion.name : '',
    answers : this.fbuild.array([])
});
```